# Get Monday of last week with JodaTime

Tags: kotlin, jodatime, android-jodatime

I need get Monday of last week E.g

> Today is 28/11/18 (wednesday)
>
> I need get 19/11/18 (monday)

I know that I can obtain Monday of the current week with

```
val monday = DateTime().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)
```

Comment: val lastMonday = monday.minusDays(7);?

Comment: @maio290 it sounds good but I need an function dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it!

```
DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(
                 DateTime().weekOfWeekyear-1)
          .withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)
```

I only have to get the week of the year and subtract one week and that is all